# JOINING 2 tables and pass values Into a Third Table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

I have 2 tables namely ItemList table and ItemChara table, having this kind of structure:

[image]

wherein, Item_Num of Item Chara is a foreign key of Item List table. Now I'm trying to JOIN these tables. With a given like these.

[image]

How can I JOIN these tables with those values to form something Like this

[image]

I'm trying to find out what is the simplest way to achieve this. I limit the colors in table Item Chara at maximum of 2 colors per Item so it won't exceed 2 colors per item. I want to make another column like Color1 and Color2 to get each color in each item. If it happens that the item doesn't have a color to pair up with, it would just left blank, or null maybe.

Sorry but I'm not sure what to call the thing that I want to do but I know the output that I want to have, so the question title might be irrelevant. I'll change it as soon as I found out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the `row_number()` window function:

```
select 
    i.item_num, i.item_name, 
    max(case when rn = 1 then ic.chara_color end) color1, 
    max(case when rn = 2 then ic.chara_color end) color2
from itemlist i 
join (
    select 
       item_num, chara_color, 
       rn = row_number() over (partition by item_num order by chara_num) 
    from itemchara
) ic on i.item_num = ic.item_num
group by i.item_num, item_name;
```

Comment: This seems to be the simplest and concise code for my work. I'll mark this as the answer. Also tried this and gave my desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will give u the required result.

```html
select A.item_num,A.Item_name,
 max(Color_1) AS Color_1,
 max(Color_2) As Color_2
from (
 select il.item_num,il.Item_name,
  (case when ic.chara_num = 1 then ic.chara_color END) AS Color_1,
  (case when ic.chara_num = 2 then ic.chara_color END) AS Color_2
 from Item_List il inner join Item_Chara ic on il.Item_Num = ic.Item_Num
) A
group by item_num,Item_name
```

This code is not tested may be have some syntax erro which u need to check and sort it out. Let me know if still ur facing some issue.

Comment: This won't give the correct results as the `chara_num` isn't just 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to other answers, but since I already made it I might post it anyway.

```
;with itemlist(itemId, itemName)
as
(
select 1,'Bag'
union ALL
select 2,'Pen'
union ALL
select 3,'Bike'
union ALL
select 4,'Shoes'
)
,itemchara(charaId, itemId, charaColor)
as
(
select 1, 1, 'Blue'
union all
select 2, 1, 'Red'
union all
select 3, 2, 'Black'
union all
select 4, 2, 'Blue'
union all
select 5, 3, 'Green'
union all
select 6, 4, 'Black'
)
,tmp
as
(
select  i.itemName
        ,c.*
        ,row_number () over ( partition by c.itemId order by c.charaId ) as r 
from    itemlist i
join    itemchara c
    on  i.itemId = c.itemId
)

select  t1. itemId
        ,t1.itemName
        ,t1.charaColor
        ,t2.charaColor
from    tmp t1
left join tmp t2
    on  t1.r+1 = t2.r
    and t1.itemId = t2.itemId
where   t1.r = 1
```